# Problem to prove for all even integers

Tags: binomial-theorem

Prove that $5^n = 3^n + \dfrac{16n (3^{n-2})}{2} + \dfrac{256n (n-2) 3^{n-4}}{8}+ ....+ 4^n$    for all even integers.

I tried finding a pattern, but was unable to do so. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: The form of the general term is not evident : could you give at least a supplementary term ? An d the fact that you end up with $4^n$ is not evident either...

Comment: Try giving as many as "in between" terms of that weird-looking sum, otherwise either it is impossible to know what the general rule to construct a summand is or else people can come up with different general terms and thus different, perhaps, results.

Comment: The general rule is extremely simple: if $n=2k$, then the left-hand side is $25^k$, which can be written as $(16 + 9)^k$, and now just apply the binomial formula. And please stop downvoting, the question is not that bad!

Comment: @AlexM. "Extremely simple"? First, there is no "general rule" since it's been proved over and over in other questions that there may be even infinite different rules. Second, even if this is *not* the case it is up to the asker, in my opinion, to make his question as clear and well defined as possible. Third, **your** "simple rule may be true...or not, of course. If the asker doesn't address these doubts I think his question deserves to be downvoted and even closed as "unclear"...or else let him say that one of his suties is to find out what the teacher meant to ask

Answer (score 1):

It is just Binomial Theorem. Let $n=2k$.
$$5^{2k}=(3^2+4^2)^k=(3^2)^k+{k\choose 1}(4^2)(3^2)^{k-1}+{k\choose 2}(4^2)^2(3^2)^{k-2}+\ldots+(4^2)^{k}$$
$$=3^n+16\dfrac n23^{n-2}+256\dfrac {\dfrac n2\left(\dfrac{n}2-1\right)}23^{n-2}+\ldots+4^n$$